# Ejecutar funcion, asociada a un button tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Es posible, ejecutar una función, que esta asociada a un command de un button de tkinter, lo que quiero es, desde otro button quiero ejecutar el command que tiene asociado un button. el button self.DESV_btn2Expandir ejecuta un funcion, pero quiero llamar a ese button para que ejecute esa funcion es posible eso??

```
self.DESV_btn2Expandir = ttk.Button(
        self.DESV_frame2,
        image=self.Expandir_icon,
        state='disabled',
        command=lambda x=self.DESVfr2_srcBackup:self.expandir(x, self.varBackup),
    )
```

Comment: Puedes usar el método invoke del boton. Puedes ver documentación de .invoke al final de esta pagina: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/button.html

Comment: Gracias, era lo que necesitaba.

Comment: Es un placer c: